# How to pass variables in Redirect() - But not in URL

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have looked all over the internet on how to redirect to a new page on my site, while passing a variable to the new page, but behind the scenes, and not in the URL like:

`www.test.com/?variable=dont.want.this.here`

I don't really want to use cookies, as they seem difficult to manage, write, and read. Are there any simple solutions to do this?

Comment: @PankajSewalia — On a redirect?

Comment: write data to a file in a certain format before redirect and got them in same format  from other servlet or jsp, your url will not change in entire web flow.. idk whether this is a good approach

Comment: @PankajSewalia — That's a huge race condition. It will break if two users hit the URL at about the same time.

Comment: yes, critical section must be synchronized and also well formatted auto-generated machine readable text file. fortunately there is only one critical section which is write to a file

Comment: "critical section must be synchronized" — synchronized to what? You can't control the order that different clients make the requests (well, unless you lock the file, and refuse to respond to any other "create file" request until the lock is released, thus making people sit on a white screen, which would be horrible (and massively, massively more complicated that using cookies)).

Comment: only one user can write to a file at one time thats what i am saying.. yes i also have doubt in this approach but its depends on need of the user whom which code is going to coded.. further you can keep track of every user's data. i just share my mind thats it. and do you sure? i cant keep order that different client make request.. mat i can do whatever i want to this by this .again thank you very much

Comment: "only one user can write to a file at one time thats what i am saying" — That is insufficient. You have to let one user write to the file. Then tell them you are redirecting them. Then get the next request from them. Then read the data from the file. Then unlock the file so that the next user can write to it. Otherwise you'll end up sharing data between different users. Since it is possible for a user to manually request the second URL, you could end up doing that anyway so it is a potential security hole.

Comment: if you have high traffic you can do thousand of stuff with them. create by category.. create by region.. create by time

Comment: first why we need lock to read a file because only lock needed here is write to a file as i say we can keep track of every user means we which record is of which user... second going by practical way processor time is 1m and far better than user clicks intervals .. i dont understand about potential security hole sorry i am little bit slow.its all happening on server as i konw

Answer (score 1):

No. There is nothing simpler than cookies for maintaining state across requests from the server.

The other option is sessions, which require a cookie to function.

Cookies are only difficult to manage if you try doing it from scratch. Find a library that will take care of it for you instead.

Comment: what about cookies disabled environment?

Comment: @PankajSewalia — Then there aren't any solutions other than storing the data in the URL (unless you want to deliver a complete HTML document with a JavaScript application to store the information in a Cookie-like data store and then be unable to access the data on the server at all).